# Benifits of Window workflow to end user

Tags: workflow-foundation

Is there any benefit of using windows workflow foundation  to the end users of the application? Also how WF fits with WCF?

Answer (score 0):

In general it should be virtual for end users what is the technology used for Service or Business layer implementation.

End users could benefit if you provide them with designer for editing workflows (implementing business logic) in run-time. That way end users could modify applications on the fly very easily.

WF and WCF are two technologies used for two different things. WCF is more communication orientated while WF is in-process workflow engine. They come together in Workflow Services, where you can create WCF services using Workflow activities.

Comment: Do you mean using windows workflow the actual user of the application can edit workflows at runtime. Could you explain more please..

Comment: @arjun If you store XAML files for your workflows in DB, then you can re-host Workflow Designer in your application an let users modify XAMLs in the tool and then store changes back into DB. Then your runtime can load XAMLs from DB and execute them.

Answer (score 0):

WF can be useful or not for the end user depend on the needs of your solution.
If you are creating a solution where users will design processes then it can be really useful.  You can create a WF designer adapted to your needs and get better user experience than use VS direclty.

I have been working in a project where our users are engineers who model workflows often in order to create processes and then execute them, and I can tell you that is really important in terms of speed and usability.

About the Workflow services, check it: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456788(v=vs.100).aspx

I hope this helps!